# Active record AND Operator

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

how do i turn this into one WHERE statement? I want to look for records where a property is an apartment and also is for sale.

```
def apartment
    @apartments_for_sale = Property.where(for_sale: true)
    @real_apartments = @apartments_for_sale.where(apartment: true)
end
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
def apartment
    @apartments = Property.where(for_sale: true, apartment: true)

     #OR via method chaining:

    @apartments = Property.where(for_sale: true).where(apartment: true)
end
```